# access isolate parent scope through nested directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In this example I'm trying to dynamically set the `limit` a given array can display.

**app-view.html**

```
<things data="things.data" settings="things.settings"></things>
```

**app-controller.js**

```
$scope.$on('thingsCallback', function(e,d){
    $scope.things = d;                
});
```

Here you will notice `limit` has not yet been set.

**things.html**

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="thing in data | limitTo: limit">
        {{thing.name}}
        <span ng-show="$index==settings.limit-1">
            <show-more min="settings.limit" max="data.length"></show-more>
        </span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**showMore.html**

```
<li>
    <a href="#" ng-click="toggle()">{{text}}</a>
</li>
```

Instead I'm using a `$watch` to wait for the async data to come in. So far so good.

**things-directive.js**

```
.directive('things', function() {
    return {
        scope : {
          data : "=",
          settings : "="
        },
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        controller: function($scope){
          $scope.$watch('settings',function(){
            if($scope.settings){
              $scope.limit = $scope.settings.limit;
            }
          });
        },
        templateUrl: 'things.html'
    };
})
```

*Problems begin:*

- When a user invokes `toggle()` to "*show more*", I'm trying to update the value of `limit` to the max value of `data.length` which is bound to `max`.
- When a user invokes `toggle()` to "*show less*", I'm trying to update the value of `limit` to the min value of `settings.length` which is bound to `min`.

**show-more-directive.js**

```
.directive('showMore', function() {
    return {
        scope : {
          min : "=",
          max : "="
        },
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        controller: function($scope){

          $scope.text = 'show more';

          $scope.toggle = function(){
            $scope.text = ($scope.max==$scope.$parent.limit)?'show more':'show less';                
            $scope.$parent.limit = ($scope.min==$scope.$parent.limit)?$scope.max:$scope.min;

            //Shows the value has updated, but the ng-repeat does not update?
            console.log($scope.$parent.limit);
          }
        },
        templateUrl: 'showMore.html'
    };
})
```

The `$scope.$parent.limit` seems to change but the the `ng-repeat` does not update to show the remaining results.

- *How do I change the isolate parent scope through a nested directive?*
- *Is there a better way to do this?*

Comment: Wrap it in $scope.$apply($scope.$parent.limit = ...); Directives don't typically fire off a digest cycle.

Comment: @ZackArgyle Getting a `$apply already in progress` error. Never used in that context --- could you provide an example please?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to recompile the element at the end of toggle():

```
.directive('showMore', function ($compile) {
  return {
    ...
    controller: function ($scope, $element) {

      $scope.toggle = function () {
        ...
        $compile($element.contents())($scope);
      }
    },
    ...
  }
```